# 404 trying to route the Upstream path to downstream path in Ocelot

Tags: .net-core, microservices, api-gateway, ocelot

I am facing this warning/error while forwarding the incoming http request to the downstream path.

> Ocelot.DownstreamRouteFinder.Middleware.DownstreamRouteFinderMiddleware:
> Warning: requestId: 80000025-0004-fd00-b63f-84710c7967bb,
> previousRequestId: no previous request id, message:
> DownstreamRouteFinderMiddleware setting pipeline errors.
> IDownstreamRouteFinder returned Error Code:
> UnableToFindDownstreamRouteError Message: Failed to match Route
> configuration for upstream path: /getDepartment, verb: GET.

Program.cs

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
       WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
       .ConfigureAppConfiguration((host, config) =>
       {
           config.AddJsonFile("ocelot.json");
       })
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Startup.cs

```cs
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
// For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOcelot(Configuration);
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    await app.UseOcelot();

    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
    });
}
```

ocelot.json

```json
{
  "ReRoutes": [
  {
    "DownstreamPathTemplate": "api/department",
    "DownstreamScheme": "http",
    "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
      "Host": "localhost",
      "Port": 44388
    }],
    "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/getDepartment",
    "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
      "Get"
    ]
  }],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "http://localhost:5000"
  }
}
```

I am getting Error 404 in this.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you are using the latest version (16.0.0), change "ReRoutes" to "Routes" in your ocelot.json.

I was having the same problem and then came across this pull request explaining it had been changed to match up with a new Microsoft reverse proxy project (YARP). Their documentation needs updating.
https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot/pull/1239

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. It is only about a Docker case sensitivity problem. I named my Ocelot config file as `ocelot.development.Json`; however, when I fixed it by using `ocelot.Development.json`; alternatively, you might you have capitalized **o**celot.*

The problem was only the upper case D or O.

Also, the PFB attached screenshot, and follow accordingly.

[image: View Image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding "DownstreamHttpMethod": "POST" in my ocelot.json file which specified the http method of the downstream API and that fixed the issue.