# Error consume route ApiGateway with ocelot and docker service

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, routes, api-gateway, ocelot

I am creating an ApiGateway with ocelot that consume an Api service in net core.
The ApiGateway and ApiService are deployed on docker with docker compose of this way:
**Docker-compose**:

```
tresfilos.webapigateway:
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}tresfilosapigateway
build: 
  context: .
  dockerfile: tresfilos.ApiGateway/ApiGw-Base/Dockerfile

tresfilos.users.service:
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}tresfilosusersservice
build: 
  context: .
  dockerfile: tresfilos.Users.Service/tresfilos.Users.Service/Dockerfile
```

**Docker-compose.override**:

```
tresfilos.webapigateway:
environment: 
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
  - IdentityUrl=http://identity-api
ports:
  - "7000:80"
  - "7001:443"
volumes:
  - ./tresfilos.ApiGateway/Web.Bff:/app/configuration

tresfilos.users.service:
environment: 
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
  - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
ports:
  - "7002:80"
  - "7003:443"
volumes:
  - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
  - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

In **configuration** ocelot apigateway i define **.json** like:

```
 "ReRoutes": [
 {
   "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{version}/{everything}",
   "DownstreamScheme": "http",
   "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
     {
       "Host": "tresfilos.users.service",
       "Port": 7002
     }
   ],
   "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{version}/user/{everything}",
   "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "POST", "PUT", "GET" ]
 },
],
"GlobalConfiguration": {
  "BaseUrl":  "https://localhost:7001"
 }
```

When i consume the ApiGateway from the url:
http://localhost:7000/api/v1/user/Login/authentication

I have the error in terminal docker:
[image]

**Why does the above error occur and how to fix it?**

Answer (score 2):

What version of Ocelot are you running?

I found another thread which has a similar looking problem and apparently from version 16.0.0 of Ocelot 'ReRoutes' was changed to 'Routes' in the Ocelot configuration file.

The thread I found was - [404 trying to route the Upstream path to downstream path in Ocelot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61997463/404-trying-to-route-the-upstream-path-to-downstream-path-in-ocelot)

Comment: Version 16.0.1, when change to Routes it generates error

Comment: What error do you get once you change it to Routes?

Comment: System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Unable to start Ocelot, errors are: Authentication Options AuthenticationProviderKey:IdentityApiKey,AllowedScopes:[] is unsupported authentication provider)'

Answer (score 2):

I fix it of this way:

1. Change ReRoutes to Routes because ocelot version is 16.0.1
2. Define config like:

   "Routes": [
   {
   "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{version}/{everything}",
   "DownstreamScheme": "http",
   "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
   {
   "Host": "tresfilos.users.service",
   "Port": 7002
   }
   ],
   "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{version}/User/{everything}"
   },
   ],
   "GlobalConfiguration": {
   "BaseUrl":  "https://localhost:7001"
   }
3. In postman i send the data in Body like json and not like paramaters.

(JasonS thanks)...